# Bulk insert into existing table - only insert new rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I've got a method to get data from existing table in database as DataTable and i want to add new rows to that datatable and then use SQLBulkCopy to only bulk insert the newly added rows and not the already existing rows, do i need to configure this somehow or will it only add the new rows anyway?

```
var myDataTable = GetExistingTableDataAsDataTable();
```

//add new rows to myDataTable.....

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Connection string"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
        {
            bulk.DestinationTableName = myDataTable.TableName;
            bulk.BatchSize = 1000;

            foreach (var column in myDataTable.Columns)
            {
                bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), column.ToString());   
            }

            bulk.WriteToServer(myDataTable); //Do i need to add DataRowState.Added here?
            bulk.Close();
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: _Do i need to add DataRowState.Added here?_ Yes, that should work

Comment: instead cant you have another DataTable with same schema and add new rows in this new DataTable and apply bulkcopy..this must be easy..is their any reason to add to existing DataTable? are you updating the rows in existing DataTable? if No! then u can create new DataTable as i said...

Comment: I don't want to do anything with the existing rows, only add new rows to the table. Yesterday i created a new datatable with same name and rows/columns, but i got error when tried to insert that because the table already exists.

Comment: please show your complete code! were do u add rows? and if u are not using the datatable then why to get rows..into datatable? and offcourse  it will give error becoz this will create ambiguity between two..how can two DataTables will have same name in same block?

Comment: I will come up with an answer soon. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary table to `bulk insert`.  Then, run a query to copy new rows over, filtering out duplicates with a `where` clause:

```
insert  YourTable
        (id, col1, col2, col3, ...)
select  id
,       col1
,       col2
,       col3
,       ...
from    TempTable t
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable yt
        where   yt.id = t.id
        )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to do this from the code.